# undefined method `evm_url'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an edit and update methods as follows:

`cmdbs_controller.rb`

```
def edit
    @evm = Evm.find(params[:id])
end

def update
    @evm = Evm.find(params[:id])
  if @evm.update(evm_params)
    redirect_to @evm
  else
     render 'edit'
  end
end
```

and routes as follows:

```
resources :cmdbs do
   get :autocomplete_client_name, :on => :collection
   collection do
     get 'test'
   end
end
```

The problem is that i get an error when submit my edit:

```
undefined method `evm_url' for #<CmdbsController:0x007fb33ac47d00>
```

and points me to the redirect_to @evm line.
BTW i am using patch and my url looks like that:

```
http://localhost:3000/cmdbs/1
```

Comment: is that your whole routes file?  If that is it, then it's weird that you're able to update evms.  look for a block that looks like `resources :evms`

Comment: @jhvnill, oh yep, I have just realized. I just was trying to use one controller cmdb for many models, and wrote actions and methods in each form_for by hand.

Comment: ah my bad, you specifically said that that controller is cmdbs which is the reason why you were able to go to the update action.  i'll post an answer since my explanation will be quite long.

Answer (score 2):

The line `redirect_to @evm` translates to `redirect_to evm_path(@evm.id)`.  It uses `evm_path` because the class of `@evm` is `Evm`.  So with that, it is expecting to have something like `resources :evms` in the routes.  This means that you have to have another controller called `EvmsController`.  Doing a `redirect_to @evm` basically redirects to the show action of `EvmsController`.  I'm not sure if that is what you want to happen but that is what Rails is trying to do.  Without any other stuff in your routes file, Rails don't know where to redirect.